# phpstorm - user different phpunit how?

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

The phpunit installed on my system is an ancient version, and I don't have the permission to change it. So I downloaded a current version of phpunit and put it (for example) in /home/myname/apps/PHPUnit/

how can i get phpstorm to use that phpunit instead of the /usr/bin/phpunit ?

regards,
malicor

Comment: PhpStorm uses has it's own helper/wrapper (for integration purposes). It loads whatever version it can find in **include_path** PHP configuration variable (yes -- it uses PHP classes directly and does not execute the actual `phpunit` command). My suggestion -- make sure that path to your PHPUnit is listed before other paths in `include_path` php.ini config variable.

Comment: i cannot edit the php.ini either, due to a lack of system permissions.

Comment: In PhpStorm, go to **Settings | PHP**, click on **"..."** button next to "Interpreter" drop-down box, on that new screen -- edit "Configuration Options" field (again via "..." button) -- see if you can override `include_path` this way -- see http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: If you cannot do this that way (for whatever reason) -- then try similar thing in **PHPUnit Run/Debug configuration** entry itself (Run | Edit Configurations) -- it has **"Interpreter Options"** field, where you can add any command line option (not just `-d` as above). For example -- you can create your own php.ini and tell PHP to use it in addition to/instead of default one.

Comment: i did that, and it seems to use my new phpunit, though the whole thing now outputs nothing, and phpstorm says:
unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly

Comment: I do not have Linux (real or in VM) and cannot help you verify the problem further. The issue can be with anything, but most likely PHP unable to find the files it require (e.g. some/additional parts of PHPUnit (rather unlikely, but ... I do not know what functionality you are using there and what you have installed) or files from your own code (maybe use bootstrap.php file where you can provide additional options/settings)). I suggest running it from command line (using your phpunit version) and see how it will behave.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have separate PEAR installations for each project, or for your user:

```
$ mkdir ~/pear
$ pear config-create ~/pear ~/pear/pear.conf
```

Now you can install packages if you pass the config file with each command:

```
$ pear -c ~/pear/pear.conf install html_quickform2
```

If you do not want to use the system-wide pear at all, move the `pear.conf` file into `~/.pearrc` - it overwrites any system settings then automatically. You don't need to specify `-c ~/pear/pear.conf` anymore.